# Redis save a hash and get a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

Can't get this to work.. I just want to save a hash to redis and then retrieve the entire hash from Redis.. not an array of values or keys, I just want the hash.. As an example:

```
jack = Redis.new
jack.hset("cart:1", "token", "456789")
pp jack.hget("cart:1", "token").class
# returns an array
```

Is it possible to pass a hash to Redis and then return that same hash as a hash, not a string or array. If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# set hash
jack.set('cart:1', { 'token' => '456789'}.to_json)
#get hash
JSON.parse jack.get('cart:1')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
jack.hgetall("cart:1")
 => {"token"=>"456789"}
```

Comment: Jacking things up like usual!

Comment: Lol, I'm sorry. It's `hgetall`, not `hget_all`. My fault. I updated my answer :)